how to make the side bar close after clicking
so I am not sure exactly how this works but here goes .so I would like to have the menu side bar close once the user clicks on a menu link item or anywhere on the body, then reopen again when the menu icon is pressed.I am sue its a simple answer but all i have tried seem to be a all in or all out method.
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content= "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 

<style>
 
 /* the side menu */
 .sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
.sidenav a {
  padding: 3px;
 margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: .9em;;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
</style>





 
 <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
<a href="#">cars</a>
<a href="#">planes</a>
<a href="#">boats</a>
<a href="#">cycles</a>
</div>
 
<span style="font-size:1.5em;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
<body>
<p>some random text some random textsome random textsome random text</p>
<p>some random text some random textsome random textsome random text</p>
<p>some random text some random textsome random textsome random text</p>
 
</body>
 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click',function(){
        $('#mySidenav').css('width', '0px');
    });
}); 
</script> 
 
<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
</script> 

when the user clicks to open the menu sidebar and selects a menu item or in the body area the sidebar must close again. I have had a look at the suggested answers and i must say the all seem very daunting, maybe because of my lack of understanding.

You can check event.target to know what element was actually clicked when listening to click event on Body and close the drawer when it is any element other than side-bar opener.


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content= "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 

<style>
 
 /* the side menu */
 .sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
.sidenav a {
  padding: 3px;
 margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: .9em;;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
</style>





 
 <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
<a href="#">cars</a>
<a href="#">planes</a>
<a href="#">boats</a>
<a href="#">cycles</a>
</div>
 
<span id="drawer-opener" style="font-size:1.5em;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
<body>
<p>some random text some random textsome random textsome random text</p>
<p>some random text some random textsome random textsome random text</p>
<p>some random text some random textsome random textsome random text</p>
 
</body>
 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click',function(e){
        if(!$(e.target).is('span#drawer-opener')) {
           $('#mySidenav').css('width', '0px');
        }
    });
}); 
</script> 
 
<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
</script>




thank you very much, it works exactly as expected, your response is greatly appreciated and i will study your answer to see where i went wrong. Thanks again.
